# Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'

Tags: java, mongodb, grails, groovy

I am trying to connect Grails project with MongoDB, but getting following error

Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'

My DataSource.groovy file-

```
    grails{
        mongo{
            host ="127.0.0.1"
            port ="27017"
            username = "blogproject"
            password = "mypassword"
            databaseName ="blogproject"
        }
    }
```

and I have removed following from BuildConfig.groovy

```
//runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.12" 
//runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
//compile ':cache:1.1.1'
```

and added following in BuildConfig.groovy

```
   compile ":mongodb:3.0.3"
```

My error stacktrace is as follows-

```
Error |
2015-08-10 11:17:15,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException: Failed to authenticate to database [blogproject], username = [blogproject], password = [m*********d]
Message: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException: Failed to authenticate to database [blogproject], username = [blogproject], password = [m*********d]
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException: Failed to authenticate to database [blogproject], username = [blogproject], password = [m*********d]
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException: Failed to authenticate to database [blogproject], username = [blogproject], password = [m*********d]
->>  285 | initializeIndices in org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    276 | createMongoTemplate in     ''
|    221 | afterPropertiesSet in     ''
|     54 | getObject in org.grails.datastore.gorm.mongo.bean.factory.MongoDatastoreFactoryBean
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8090/blogproject
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

I also have added following user in MongoDB for database "blogproject" for authentication

```
> use blogproject
switched to db blogproject
> show users;
{
        "_id" : "blogproject.blogproject",
        "user" : "blogproject",
        "db" : "blogproject",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "blogproject"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "dbAdmin",
                        "db" : "blogproject"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "dbOwner",
                        "db" : "blogproject"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "userAdmin",
                        "db" : "blogproject"
                }
        ]
}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like username and/or password is wrong:

```
Failed to authenticate to database [blogproject], username = [blogproject], password = [m*********d]
```

Comment: @Tushar but the error message say's some other things. Maybe you connect to a different DB as you expected?